# CSS change an element content on hover from different element

Tags: css, html, hover

Is it possible **in CSS** to change an element's content when hovered from a different element? Let's say for example, I have this divs A, B, C, D, E, F. I want to show some text in A when I hover in B. a different text will appear in A if I hover over in C. and the same goes for the rest. All the changes takes place in A when hovered in divs B to F.

Comment: Post some `HTML` example.

Comment: Depends but most likely you might need jquery..what have you tried? Add code :)

Comment: With JavaScript it would be pretty easy to do this using mouse over events. If  you show some HTML, I could demo up some JS

Comment: Is your text also dynamic (or) text is pre-defined? What browsers do you have to support? You can have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/szrxD/) for a sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently this is not possible with CSS only. You can adjust the styles of children or upcoming siblings. But you *can't* set the styles of previous siblings or parent elements.

So regarding your case you could do:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* next sibling only */
div.a:hover + div.b { /* styles for b when hovering a */ }

/* general sibling selector */
div.a:hover ~ div.c { /* styles for c when hovering a */ }
div.b:hover ~ div.c { /* styles for c when hovering b */ }
```

You can't go the other way, from `b` to `a` for example.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/YsHA4/)

Comment: You could hack it with negative margins?

Comment: Of course, you can still style it to your needs, so that the last sibling will appear as the first, as @JuanMendes suggested.

Comment: I almost posted that the demo link is missing before realizing that the link was actually in the next line :)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the general sibling selector `~` and by having a matching div to go with each of the hovered divs. This works in the latest version of all browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/s8uwu/

### HTML

```
<div id="a">Hello A</div>
<div id="b">Hello B</div>
<div id="c">Hello C</div>
<div id="d">Hello D</div>
<div id="e">Hello E</div>
<div id="text">
    <div class="a">From A</div>
    <div class="b">From B</div>
    <div class="c">From C</div>
    <div class="d">From D</div>
    <div class="e">From E</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#a:hover~#text .a,
#b:hover~#text .b,
#c:hover~#text .c,
#d:hover~#text .d,
#e:hover~#text .e{
    display: block;
}

#text div{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I posted a fiddle on similar lines in the comments (not accusing of copying, do not mistake). The only point is this approach will work if the text (like From A etc) is pre-defined. If not, setting a random text value into the div would be very challenging.

Comment: @Harry where does it say that you need random text? The OP doesn't want a script, you have to store the text in your HTML, or in the CSS as insertusernamehere

Comment: The question isn't very clear on that. That is what I am trying to say. OP should clarify more on what *some text* means.

Answer (score 0):

Simply from its name, **CSS(Cascading Style Sheet)** is **only for applying style/appearance** in a convenient way.

Hence it ***does not at all deal with the content*** of an web-page.

However You definitely can do it with the help of **JavaScript** as follows-

```
<div id="a" onmouseover="document.getElementById('b').innerHTML='ijkl';">abcd</div>
<div id="b">efgh</div>
```

Comment: That's not the question though. CSS does let you do it, OP wants to know how

Comment: @JuanMendes Your answer specify how to hide the contents but not how to change it. So you also dont give a solution to it...

Comment: It gives the appearance of changing, that is surely good enough, since CSS deals with appearance

Comment: @JuanMendes but he asked for how to change the content. Can you answer that??? It's not about good/bad but about what he is asking for. Even you r telling so...

Comment: I guess if you're going to be very particular about the wording that would be true. However, the only thing that is clear is that the OP wants it with CSS, not with JS. And actually, the answer from inserusernamehere does actually change the content from the CSS

Comment: We weren't thought jQuery not until yesterday. Everything seems easy on jQuery but I want to find something out just using CSS :D My idea of how I can do it is assigning a variable that contains the text (the texts comes from a database). All are hidden under the Div A and will have the opacity put into 100 on hover :D